# Polynomial curve sketching on blender

Tags: python, bezier-curves, mathematics

I know that blender is able to draw mathematics curves using function, example:

[How to draw a flat ellipse surface in Blender with the following known dimensions?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67069/how-to-draw-a-flat-ellipse-surface-in-blender-with-the-following-known-dimension?newreg=85d367102c9b4045a7b01c654b54040f)

Is there any code or method to insert a function $f(x)$ and get the curve?

[image]

How to limit the points of the curve as in the example in red?

[image]

Above, an ellipse is drawn in blender using the Bezier curve, through code and mathematical equations, to exemplify this question.

Comment: try something similar to the python code in: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271855/how-do-i-render-the-implicit-function-z2-x-y-1z-y-0-in-blender/271857#271857 then just create a loop with $px$ iterating from range $2-8$ and u will get the resulting $py$ with substituting each $x$ into your equation $py=0.09x^2+0.42x+0.49$. then plot it with $pz=(0,0,0)$ since your case is just 2 dimensional.

Comment: This codes works!

Answer (score 2):

Try this script. Notice that your $f(x)$ function is in the `get_graph_y` definition which accepts an `x` value input in the range $2-8$ and computes its corresponding `y` value from the function. You can change the range and the function to anything as long as its of the form $y=y(x)$ and the script will plot the graph.

```
import bpy

def get_object(name):
    objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
    if name in objects:
        return objects[name]
    m = bpy.data.meshes.new(name + "-mesh")
    o = bpy.data.objects.new(name, m)
    #o.modifiers.new(name, 'SKIN')
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(o)
    return o 

def get_range(start, end, step = 2):
    return [v * 0.1 for v in range(start * 10, end * 10, step)]

def get_graph_y(x):
    return 0*x**3 - 0.09*x**2 + 0.42*x + 0.49

def draw_graph():
    verts = []

    for px in get_range(2, 8):
        py = get_graph_y(px)
        pz = 0
        verts.append([px, py, pz])

    edges = []
    for i in range(len(verts)-1):
        edges.append((i, i+1))

    o = get_object("graph")
    m = o.data
    m.clear_geometry()
    m.from_pydata(verts, edges, ())

draw_graph()
```

Take note that you can also easily plot this using Geometry Nodes. I'll update my answer with a GN solution later.

Comment: ////////Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 36, in <module>
  File "\Text", line 34, in draw_graph
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\modules\bpy_types.py", line 564, in from_pydata
    self.vertices.foreach_set("co", tuple(chain.from_iterable(vertices)))
TypeError: couldn't access the py sequence

Comment: I tried using "m.from_pydata(verts, (), ())" and the error doesnt change, but the code looks great!

Comment: Worked!!! Thank you!